# fast calculation to get the minimum sum?

Tags: sum

I have a data like this

```
row1: x1 x2 x3... xn, y1,y2,...yn
row2: x2,x3,....xj, y4,y5,...ym
.....
row 1 million, x6,x2,x7...xk, y2,y3,...yl
```

each row , the number of x and y can be one million or even more

each row, some number of x or y can have the same value.like row 1 and row 2 have x2 in common.

my goal is to find which row give me the smallest sum of x and y.
for example the sum of row 1 is  sum(x1+x2,..+xn+y1+y2+...yn).

The exhaustive way can work but will be very slow since there will be one million * one million operations,
I believe there are some clever ways to work.

Thanks

Update:

Actually the above problem come from a matrix partition:, give a matrix like below with 5x5

```
1 2 3 4 5
2 3 4 5 6
2 3 4 5 8
9 1 2 3 5
1 5 2 5 6
```

there are at least five ways to partition this matrix into two submatrix , for example,

```
1 2 | 3 4 5
2 3 | 4 5 6
----+------
2 3 | 4 5 8
9 1 | 2 3 5
1 5 | 2 5 6
```

I get two sub matrix

```
1 2
2 3
```

and

```
4 5 8 
2 3 5
2 5 6
```

so actually  1 2 2 3 is the x I refer, and 4 5 8 2 3 5 2 5 6 are the y I mention.
so each row is a kind of splitting in the matrix.
I am not sure I am clear or not? please add comments.

Comment: What is the pattern that controls which rows have which elements in common?  If there is no pattern, you have no choice but to calculate each sum from scratch.

Comment: Is there some relationship between the numbers in each row so that you don't need to just add them again to get the next sum?

Comment: Actually these numbers are all come from a matrix, it is a matrix partition problem, I just transform it into a number problem.

Answer (score 0):

From what I am seeing above is that the x and y pattern overlap on both rows, so given a list {x1, x2, ... xn} and {y1, y2, .. ym}

given i,j,k,l in (1, n)

and   o,p,q,r in (1, m)

row one is: { xi, xi+1, ... ,xj }{ yo, yo+1, ... , yp }

row two is: { xk, xk+1, ... ,xl }{ yq, yq+1, ... , yr }

so what you really need to find is the difference between the rows and compare that, and only sum that up since the overlap (part that has the same values) will have the same sum.

is there anything more you can tell us about the two lists? are they sorted? do you know what the list of x and y are independently of the rows? can a value in the list of x appear in the list of y? the Are they sorted in any way?

knowing these things would make is a lot faster to figure out what you need.

if not you will have to walk the rows and determine the overlaps.

Update:

this assumes we only decompose thru the diagonal but you can generalize the algorithm to do others.

Using your example above lets see if we can work it, I am grouping the numbers by x and y sets.

Row 1: {1}{3 4 5 6 3 4 5 8 1 2 3 5 5 2 5 6}
Row 2: {1 2 2 3} {4 5 8 2 3 5 2 5 6} so we added to x {2 3} from the second column and {2} from the second row.
                                        we removed from y {3 3 1 5} from the second column and {4 5 6} from the second row
Row 3: {1 2 3 2 3 4 2 3 4}{3 5 5 6} so we added to x {3 4 4} from the third column and {2 3} from the thrid row.
                                        we removed from y {4 2 2 } from the thrid column and {5 8} from the third row

Note I did not calculate the total sum. just the differences from row 1

so if we generalize for each row other than 1. (if you do not need the total sums then do not compute row 1 at all)

for an nxn matric M

delat row 1 = 0;

for r = 2 to r < n

for i=1 to i <= r, and j=1 to j < r (so we do not count elemtn M(r,r) twice)

Delta row r = Delta row (r-1) + sum M(r, i) + sum M(j, r) - sum M(r, n-i) - sum M(n-j, r)

Rows that are less than row 1 will be negative. you canjust keep the smallest row delta you have seen so far as you go and you will know which decomp sum is minimum.

does this make sense?

Comment: hi, it is not a homework, it is some practical problem I face. two lists are not sorted. A value in list x is not in the list of y. both are not sorted. Determine the overlap may also incur some costs, but is it worthwhile to do that?

Comment: You may be able to leverage the construction process of your rows and compute the sums for the first and a delta for each consecutive row. It would be great if we could share a white board. :( I will take a stab at it on my side but at first glance, this is going to be expensive in time complexity. Lets see what we can figure out.

Comment: I am also think of sort the number and check the overlap, but I am afraid it will be not cheap than direct exhausitive counting

Comment: I am not sure that will help all that much you already have everything you need from construction. besides the overlap would only help you in the case of a few rows I did not catch that on the first read. Seeing the way its done now you will always have n rows for an nxn matrix correct? do you always split the matrix down the diagonal? you may need to do some matrix manipulation. what is the end goal of this minimum sum? as in what will it tell you?

Comment: also what is your time table on this I am sure you need this done by yesterday, we could try a brute force and see if it will work for ya. I think we can get it down in O(n^2) ish what language are you using?

Comment: thanks for thinking this problem with me. Given a nxn matrix, there will be numerous way of splitting it into two submatrix, n1xn1 and n2xn2, where n1+n2=n. matrix n1xn1 and n2xn2 has no overlap. Imagine, you cut the matrix by column into half first, then horizontally cut the row into half, you will get four submatrix, right? I need two that down the diagonal. Imagine each cell of the matrix is a distance value, this is a problem pf how to find the splitting that can best separate the whole group into two sub groups. would like to discuss with you more.

Comment: if do it by brute-force way, it is O(n^2), I want to cut the time down.

Comment: check my update, do you think that will speed things up for you?

Comment: I did not understand there is any new insight from your update, you mention O(n^2), is there anyway to make it faster

Comment: I think that my suggestion will be in the tune of O(n) since you will count any elment of your matrix at most twice.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10839/discussion-between-user974270-and-rob)